# Spacemacsのorg-modeで使う補完ワードを自分で定義したい

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Spacemacsのorg-modeを使ってよく文章を書くのですが、よく使うキーワードを補完候補としてポップアップ表示できたらいいのになあと思っていました。

現在spacemacsの補完機能である"auto-completion"レイヤーは有効にしておりますが
日本語の文章を書いていると、よく分からないところで補完候補が出てきたりします。
自分自身で補完対象のキーワードを設定することはできますか？

尚、".spacemacs"内で"auto-completion"レイヤーの設定を以下のようにしてあります。

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
 (auto-completion :variables
                  auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t)
)
```

この設定だとスニペットとして登録すれば、ポップアップ表示はされるのですがスニペットは普通、定型文のようなものに設定すると思うので用途が違います。

同じようなことをしている方がいらっしゃいましたら、やり方をお教えください。

**環境**
OSX 10.11.6
Emacs 26.1
Spacemacs 200.13
Org-mode 9.1.14